# Calculating $P(a+2X \ge b + X, X\le Y\le Z)$ When $X,Y,Z$ are independent of each other and each have CDF $F$?

Tags: probability

> Calculating $P(a+2X \ge b + X, X\le Y\le Z)$ When $X,Y,Z$ are independent of each other and each have CDF $F$?

Edit: So what follows below is indeed not correct. What am I looking for in an answer now, is for someone to provide some intuition **regarding why independence of $X$ from $Y$ and $Z$ and independence of $Y$ from $Z$ indeed does not mean that the events $X\leq Y$ and $Y\leq Z$ are independent**.

I initially asked this question because I suspected this but I honestly have almost no intuition for why this would be true.
My attempt: I believe I can write
$$P(a+2X \ge b + X, X\le Y\le Z) =P[(X\geq b-a) \cap (X\leq Y) \cap (Y\leq Z)] =                 P[(X\geq b-a)\big\vert (X\leq Y)\cap Y\leq Z] \cdot P((X\leq Y)\cap Y\leq Z)$$ and then
$$
P[(X\geq b-a)\big\vert (X\leq Y)\cap Y\leq Z] \cdot P((X\leq Y)\cap Y\leq Z) =\\  P[(X\geq b-a)\big\vert (X\leq Y)\cap Y\leq Z] \cdot P(X\leq Y \vert Y\leq Z)\cdot P(Y\leq Z)$$

and then because $X$ independent of $Y$ and Independent of $Z$ and $Y$ independent of $Z$,
$$ \tag{1}
P[(X\geq b-a)\big\vert (X\leq Y)\cap Y\leq Z] \cdot P(X\leq Y \vert Y\leq Z)\cdot P(Y\leq Z) =\\
P(X\geq b-a)P(X\leq Y) P(Y\leq Z)$$
which is the result I could have arrived at directly by noting $P(A\cap B\cap C) =P(A)P(B)P(C)$ when $A,B,C$ are independent.

Then I could write $(1)$ as $(1-F(b-a))(F(Y))(F(Z))$. (and then if $F$ is something simple like Uniform CDF this is an easy calculation).

Can someone confirm that this is correct? I am not sure whether $X\leq Y\leq Z$ prompts a different approach than $X\leq Y$ (that is having 2 inequalities on Random variables instead of one inequality). I can't see why it would though.

Comment: The step $$P[(X\geq b-a)\big\vert (X\leq Y)\cap Y\leq Z] =P(X\geq b-a)$$ is quite wrong. So is the step $$P(X\leq Y \vert Y\leq Z)=P(X\leq Y)$$ For example if $(X,Y,Z)$ is i.i.d. with some continuous distribution, then $$P(X\leq Y \vert Y\leq Z)=\frac13\ne\frac12=P(X\leq Y)$$

Comment: If $(X,Y,Z)$ is i.i.d. with some continuous distribution, then, for every $c$, a symmetry argument yields $$P(Z\geqslant Y\geqslant X\geqslant c)=\frac16P(X\geqslant c,Y\geqslant c,Z\geqslant c)=\frac16P(X\geqslant c)P(Y\geqslant c)P(Z\geqslant c)=\frac16(1-F(c))^3$$

Comment: @Did So independence of $X$ from $Y$ and $Z$ and independence of $Y$ from $Z$ indeed does not mean that the events $X\leq Y$ and $Y\leq Z$ are independent, correct? Because if they were then it would be the case that $$P(X\leq Y\vert Y\leq Z) = \frac{P((X\leq Y)\cap (Y\leq Z))}{P(Y\leq Z)} =\frac{ P(X\leq Y)\cdot P(Y\leq Z)}{P(Y\leq Z)} = P(X\leq Y) = \frac{1}{2}$$ which is not true. So I guess what I am wondering is whether you (or someone else) can provide some intuition for why those two events are not independent. I will edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: Because they both require Y.

Comment: @Did Thank you. Lastly, for $$P(Z\geqslant Y\geqslant X\geqslant c)=\frac16P(X\geqslant c,Y\geqslant c,Z\geqslant c)$$, I think the $\frac16$ is from $P(Z\geqslant Y\geqslant X) = \frac16$ but if that's the case how are you sure that $(z\geqslant Y\geqslant X)$ is independent of $(X\geqslant c,Y\geqslant c,Z\geqslant C)$? Is it just because this essentially just truncates the distribution (evenly)?

Comment: I did not say that. Just use that for every permutation $(U,V,W)$ of $(X,Y,Z)$, $$P(U\geqslant V\geqslant W\geqslant c)$$ is the same.

Comment: @Did Okay, Thank you for helping me so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, my derivation was incorrect. Specifically, 
$$P[(X\geq b-a)\big\vert (X\leq Y)\cap Y\leq Z] \not=P(X\geq b-a)$$
and
$$P(X\leq Y \vert Y\leq Z)\not=P(X\leq Y)$$
This is because $X$ independent of $Y$ and $Z$ and $Y$ independent of $Z$ does not mean that the events $X\leq Y$ and $Y\leq Z$ are independent. The reason these two events are not independent is because they both require $Y$.